# auditd does not save rules and overrides the edited rules after each deamon restart

Tags: ubuntu, linux-audit

I have `auditd` in Ubuntu and I'm trying to apply some rules but everytime I edit `audit.rules` file and restart `auditd` deamon it generates a new file. How can I keep the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit `/etc/audit/audit.rules` directly, like it says at the top of the file, its contents is generated:

```
## This file is automatically generated from /etc/audit/rules.d
```

You need to place your custom rules in a new file in `/etc/audit/rules.d/`. For example:

`/etc/audit/rules.d/acmecorp.rules`:

```
-a user,never -F uid=zabbix -F exe=/usr/bin/sudo
```

You can regenerate `/etc/audit/audit.rules` with the `augenrules` utility:

```
$ augenrules --check
/sbin/augenrules: Rules have changed and should be updated

$ augenrules --load
No rules
enabled 1
failure 1
pid 1114646
[..]
```

The rules should now appear in `/etc/audit/audit.rules` and should be active. You can check with `auditctl -l`:

```
$ auditctl -l
-a never,user -F uid=114 -F exe=/usr/bin/sudo
```